# Complete request on error in Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

the problem is when an error happens, the complete callback is not working to hide the loading indicator. **and I don't want to use finalize operator in every request**. it should be done in the error interceptor.

**error.interceptor.ts**

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
    timeout(timeOut),
    catchError((error: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status !== 401) {
                const errorMessage = typeof error.error === 'string' ? error.error : 'Unhandled Error! please try again'
                this.toast.danger('', errorMessage);
            }
            if (error.status === 440) this.userService.logout(true);
        }
            
        return throwError(error);
    })
);
```

**sample.component.ts**

```
this.proxy.CreateVersion(model).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(
    result => {
        console.log(result)
    },
    console.error,
    () => this.loading.grid = false        // Not Working
)
```

Comment: You have `this.loading.grid` in the `complete` handler. It sounds like you want to put it into the `error` handler instead.

Comment: Yes but I want to hide the loading on error and success. should I put it in both error and complete callbacks ? I need a better way to do this

Comment: It should works like that. Are you sure you are going in the `complete` method by using a log ?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. the complete callback works only if the request completed without errors. so i need to hide loading in error and complete callbacks, and it does not look like a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error, you catch and release

```js
catchError(err => {
  /* do some stuff */
  return throwError(err);
})
```

This is effectively the equivalent of `tap` for an error. It lets you do something in the event of a error without changing anything about your stream.

If, however, you want to catch your error and then complete you stream successfully (now that you've caught and handled your error), that typically looks like this.

```js
catchError(err => {
  /* do some stuff */
  return of({defaultValue});
})
```

```js
catchError(err => {
  /* do some stuff */
  return EMPTY;
})
```

Both of these approaches turn an errored stream into a successful stream that will call the `complete` handler instead of the `error` handler in the final subscription.